# Regex - find every occurrence of integer surrounded by space and coma

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

```
"121 fd412 4151 3213, 421, 423 41241 fdsfsd"
```

And I need to get 3213 and 421 - because they both have space in front of them, and a coma behind.

The result will be set inside the string array...How can I do that?

`"\\d+"` catches every integer.

`"\s\\d+(,)"` throws some memory errors.

EDIT.

space to the left `(<-)` of the number, coma to the right `(->)`

EDIT 2.

```
string mainString = "Tests run: 5816, 8346, 28364 iansufbiausbfbabsbo3 4";
MatchCollection c = Regex.Matches(a, @"\d+(?=\,)");
var myList = new List<String>();
foreach(Match match in c)
{
    myList.Add(match.Value);
}            
Console.Write(myList[1]);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What kind of memory errors? This string doesn't seem that large.

Comment: 421 does not have a space behind it, it has a comma.

Comment: 3213 has no coma behind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex syntax is incorrect for wanting to match both digits, if you want them as separate results, you could do:

```
@"\s(\d+),\s(\d+)\s"
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fB7iO8/2)

### Edit

```
@"\s(\d+),"
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hG2rV3/1)

Comment: Thanks! However the string may get larger in time, so I wanna retrieve all number matching this pattern.

Comment: `12 52 14, 25 14 51, 42, 95, 21` - should result in `[14, 51, 42, 95]`

Comment: @user3486978 Do you want the check the example in your original question? It disagrees with that example.

Comment: Ok, it works now. But I only want to retrieve the number, without space and the coma...is there a way to do this?

Comment: Change `myList.Add(match.Value);` to `myList.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);`

Answer (score 0):

`\s\\d+(,)`:

- `\s` is not properly escaped, should be `\\s`, same as for `\\d`
- `\\d` matches single digit, you need `\\d+` - one or more consecutive digits
- `(,)` captures comma, do you really need this? seems like you need to capture a number, so `\\s(\\d+),`
- you said "because they both have space behind them, and a coma in front", so probably `,\\s(\\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

How about this expression :

```
 " \d+,"  // expression without the quotes
```

it should find what you need.

How to work with regular expression can you check on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you're looking for something like `,<space><digit>` not `,<digit><space>`

If so, try [this](http://regex101.com/r/fB7iO8/3):

```
, (\d+)   //you might need to add another backslash as the others have noted
```

Well, based on your new edit

```
\s(\d+),
```

Test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/fB7iO8/4)

Answer (score 0):

It's all you need, only the numbers

```
\d+(?=\,)
```

[image: regex]

[image: Console]

Comment: I just edited the post, take a look at the code. It doesn't work.

Comment: Just take a look at the picture I added. It's exactly your scenario. @user3486978

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
\s(\d+),  // or maybe you'll need a double slash \\
```

Output:

```
3213
421
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cX0gN3/2)